# BroadcastReceiver with MEDIA_BUTTON intent doesn't receive anything

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have this simple receiver:

```
public class RemoteControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Something received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And this is supposed to show this Toast message when a volume button is pressed.
Also, I registered it in my manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I am currently using API26. I read about this here:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/06/allowing-applications-to-play-nicer.html

So, I can even use KeyEvent here, right ? But this doesn't receive and show anything.... Possible help, please ?

Comment: `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` does not pertain to volume buttons. That is for wired/wireless headphones with play/pause and similar buttons.

Comment: Oh okay. So, is there an action that reacts to volume buttons ?

Comment: I am not aware of any broadcasts for that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try out with this java code :

```
 mediaButtonReceiver = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), 
  MediaButtonReceiver.class.getName());

 mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

  mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mediaButtonReceiver);
```

To unregistered:

```
  mAudioManager.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(mediaButtonReceiver);
```

Comment: I am sorry if mistaken, but does this code react to VOLUME buttons (on phone, not headphones for example)?